# Поменять тему для изменения подсветки синтаксиса

Tags: intellij-idea, настройки

Хочу поменять подсветку синтаксиса на какую либо другую(не стандартную), например как в SumblimeText. Как это сделать и где скачать темы для intellij idea?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> подсветку синтаксиса

file -> settings -> editor -> colors&fonts

> где скачать

file -> settings -> plugins